# How to free unwanted memory of app, which is unnecessarily holds?

Tags: ios, memory-management

After using 15-20 minuts, my app is taking around 50-60 MB memory because of there is lots of db operations.

So, anyone can tell me how to free unwanted memory of my app, which is unnecessarily holds?

```
NOTE : I am working on ARC based project
```

Comment: Profile your app using instruments - Leaks, Allocations. And how do you expect us to know what your app is doing.

Comment: Debugging memory leaks can be very challenging. If you have never done it before, then check out a few tutorials on the usage of the Instruments tool. And even then it will take a lot of time to understand what you see there. As a consequence, it is impossible to answer your current question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go through this one [Finding Memory Leaks in iOS Application](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html)

**Locating Memory Issues in App**

[image]

The following configuration options provide memory-specific information through the Activity Monitor

- Physical Memory Wired
- Physical Memory Active
- Physical MemoryInactive
- Physical Memory Used
- Physical Memory Free
- Total VM Size
- VM Page In Bytes
- VM Page Out Bytes
- VM Swap Used

**Leaks Found**

[image]

To locate leaking memory
Open the Leaks instrument.

Choose your app from the Choose Target pop-up menu.

Click the Record button.

Exercise your app to execute code, and click the Stop button when leaks are displayed.

Click any leaked object that is identified in the Detail pane.

Within the Extended Detail pane, double-click an instruction from your code.

Click the Xcode icon in the Detail pane to open that code in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Use Instruments. There are plenty of tutorials, [here](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) is one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage memory allocations in the proper way, even if you work in ARC enabled environment.
For example never allocate your object with `strong` reference when `weak` will do it. Consider using also `copy`, `assign` references, in the right places.

Also pointing your objects to nil, after you've done with them, will help.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/ios-app-builder/understand-memory-management-under-arc/239

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

Dont hold objects in memory if they are not visible to user especially it have blob object.
Try to replace sqlite with Core Data. it many advantages like

- Relationship are object are not auto fetched
- Blobs are not fetched unless you try to ask blob info for that particular records
- NSFetchRequestController lets you fetch fetch pages in paging instead all at once
- If you receive memory waring, you can reset NSManagedContext object any time, you need to query again for those faulted objects. Just use object id to regenerate object

Many of things above can also be done with sqlite, but you will have make your own mechanism to do so.

Use instrument to check if you not leaking any memory. If you are downloading something with caching enabled, [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses] to free some memory